# Unable to install Chrome or Safari extensions after creating new user account

Tags: macos, user-account, web-browser, safari-extensions, chrome-extensions

*Mac OS X El Capitan*

This ordeal began when I was unable to connect Time Machine to a newly purchased Time Capsule; it still wanted to hang on to an older external drive which had died. I called Apple and they instructed me to create a new user account and try connecting the Time Capsule. This worked and I was able to back up to Time Capsule.

But. Reinstallation of Google Chrome extensions fails. First I see a dialog box I didn't see before:

[image: Chrome extension download dialog box]

Then when I click 'Save', it displays this:

[image: Error has occurred; download interrupted]

And in the download bar, the item is tagged "Failed -- insufficient permissions".

Extension installation fails for Safari also.

I tried booting into the recovery partition and repairing the user permissions, but that did not solve the problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You don't describe how the Safari extensions fail to install, but if you had the same problem as I you would first get a dialog box saying that something went wrong, and the extension install button is then replaced with a red "installation failed" message.

I solved this by going into the keychain manager preferences and resetting the default keychain. After that all extensions installed normally.

For some reason, every time I started Safari it asked for the password to the default keychain, and being a freshly installed OS I just typed the only password I had -- my user password -- which it didn't accept. Apparently Safari just couldn't verify the extensions' signatures.

I got the idea while reading [Repeated "Safari wants to use the 'Local Items' keychain" alert](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/312424)

Answer (score 0):

Every one

I know the question is too old to answer now, But I think my answer will save any ones time some day, anyways here is a solution of this problem.

For fixing chrome "Insufficient Permissions" error issue, solutions as follows

In terminal fire following command

```
sudo chown -Rf <YOUR USER ACCOUNT NAME>:staff ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome
```

This will allow chrome to write down new extensions files to your system.

Comment: OP here. I can't remember how I solved this. It may have had something to do with SIP. Or maybe I upgraded to Sierra. Anyway, thanks for the answer.